# Why are my objects stored in the same location?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ programming and have run into a problem regarding object location.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class MineralRocks
{
public:
    int AtomicNumber;
    string Symbol;
    string NameOfMetal;
    double MeltingPoint;
    double BoilingPoint;
    double Density;
    double AtomicRadius;
    string DiscoveryName;
    double SpeedOfSound;
    string ProducerCountry;
    double ProducerCountryPercent;

    //default constructor
    MineralRocks() {};

    //initialized consntructor
    MineralRocks(int a_num, string sym, string n_metal, double melt, double boil, double dense, double a_radius, 
        string discoName, double SoS, string p_country, double p_CPercent)
    {
        a_num = AtomicNumber;
        sym = Symbol;
        n_metal = NameOfMetal;
        melt = MeltingPoint;
        boil = BoilingPoint;
        dense = Density;
        a_radius = AtomicRadius;
        discoName = DiscoveryName;
        SoS = SpeedOfSound;
        p_country = ProducerCountry;
        p_CPercent = ProducerCountryPercent;
    };

    //member function melting point conversion
    double mConversion() {
        return MeltingPoint - 217.15;
    }

    //member function boiling point conversion
    double bConversion() {
        return BoilingPoint - 217.15;
    }

    //member function display results
    void display() {
        cout << "**********Results**********" << endl;
        cout << "Atmoic Number: " << AtomicNumber << endl;
        cout << "Atomic Symbol: " << Symbol << endl;
        cout << "Metal Name: " << NameOfMetal << endl;
        cout << "Melting Point(K): " << MeltingPoint << endl;
        cout << "Melting Point(C): " << mConversion() << endl;
        cout << "Boiling Point(K): " << BoilingPoint << endl;
        cout << "Boiling Point(C): " << bConversion() << endl;
        cout << "Density: " << Density << endl;
        cout << "Atmoic Radius: " << AtomicRadius << endl;
        cout << "Discovorer: " << DiscoveryName << endl;
        cout << "Speed of Sound: " << SpeedOfSound << endl;
        cout << "Production Country: " << ProducerCountry << endl;
        cout << "Production %: " << ProducerCountryPercent << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    //vector (container) of class to store created objects
    vector<MineralRocks> minerals(3);
    MineralRocks Gold(79, "Au", "Gold", 1337.33, 3243, 19.30, 144, "Jeande Marignac", 2030, "China", 15.734);
    minerals.push_back(Gold);
    MineralRocks Lithium(3, "Li", "Lithium", 453.65, 1603, 0.534, 152, "Johan August Arfwedson", 6000, "Australia", 12);
    minerals.push_back(Lithium);
    MineralRocks Uranium(92, "U", "Uranium", 1405.3, 4404, 19.1, 156, "Martin Heinrich Klaproth", 3155, "Canada", 33.3);
    minerals.push_back(Uranium);

    //for loop, display object data with system pause
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        minerals[x].display(); 
        system("PAUSE");
        cout << "********End Results********" << endl;
    };

    cout << ">>>>> Total Metal Density Combined: " << minerals[0].Density + minerals[1].Density + minerals[2].Density << endl;
};
```

The real question comes to my output, which is as follows:

```
Atomic Number: -842150451
Atomic Symbol: 
Metal Name:
Melting Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Melting Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Density: -6.27744e+66
Atomic Radius: -6.27744e+66
Discoverer: 
Speed of Sound: -6.27744e+66
Production Country: 
Production %: -6.27744e+66
Press any key to continue...

Atomic Number: -842150451
Atomic Symbol: 
Metal Name:
Melting Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Melting Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Density: -6.27744e+66
Atomic Radius: -6.27744e+66
Discoverer: 
Speed of Sound: -6.27744e+66
Production Country: 
Production %: -6.27744e+66
Press any key to continue...

Atomic Number: -842150451
Atomic Symbol: 
Metal Name:
Melting Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Melting Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(K): -6.27744e+66
Boiling Point(C): -6.27744e+66
Density: -6.27744e+66
Atomic Radius: -6.27744e+66
Discoverer: 
Speed of Sound: -6.27744e+66
Production Country: 
Production %: -6.27744e+66
Press any key to continue...
```

I am trying to figure out why my objects all seem to be stored in the same location. In addition, the strings are not being displayed at all. I realize it is probably something very simple that I am merely overlooking, but what is it?

Comment: `vector<MineralRocks> minerals(3);` starts out with 3 objects already in it.

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you think they're stored in the same memory location?

Comment: Removing the declaration of three objects within the vector, I still get the same results.

Comment: @PaulEvans a CVE is provided... not quite minimal

Comment: Are you confusing `a = b;` with `b = a;`? They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Using *ctor-initializer* syntax is a good idea and would have avoided this problem

Comment: General rule before going anywhere near that "ask question" button: *Narrow your problem down.* No problem statement needs seventeen instances of a thing that all have the same concern.

Comment: And now when you change `AtomicNumber` etc. to `const` (they aren't going to change anytime soon are they?) you realize you should've used a member initializer list in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and no they are not going to change.  I've been doing C++ for only a few weeks at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I immediately noticed that your constructor is incorrect. You are not correctly setting the object's member variables with your current constructor.

Please follow as seen below.

```
MineralRocks(int a_num, string sym, string n_metal, double melt, double boil, double dense, double a_radius, 
    string discoName, double SoS, string p_country, double p_CPercent)
{
    AtomicNumber = a_num;
    Symbol = sym;
   // fix the rest
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much.  That fixed it.  Figured it was something simple that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered already. My answer shows some ways you can use C++11 to avoid having to write a bunch of boilerplate code (in particular, your big repetitive constructor) and thereby reduce the possibility of errors.

The "trick" here is to separate out just the variables into a class with no other constructors. Such a class is called an *aggregate* and it lets you do something called *aggregate initialization*: you don't need to write a constructor, you can just pass in the list of values and they get applied to the members in order.    (This is the only way initialization worked in C).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct MineralRocksBase
{
    int AtomicNumber;
    string Symbol;
    string NameOfMetal;
    double MeltingPoint;
    double BoilingPoint;
    double Density;
    double AtomicRadius;
    string DiscoveryName;
    double SpeedOfSound;
    string ProducerCountry;
    double ProducerCountryPercent;
};

struct MineralRocks : MineralRocksBase
{ 
// Construction with no arguments: Zero out all the numbers, instead of leaving garbage values
    MineralRocks(): MineralRocksBase{} {}

// All other construction attempts, except copy-construction, are forwarded on to MineralRocksBase
    template<typename... Args>
    MineralRocks(int a1, Args&&... args): MineralRocksBase{a1, args...} {}

// The rest of your functionality.
// Functions which do not modify the object should be marked "const".
    double mConversion() const { return MeltingPoint - 217.5; }
    double bConversion() const { return BoilingPoint - 217.5; }

    void display() const
    {
        cout << NameOfMetal << ", " << mConversion() << ".\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
// Make the vector - braced initialization
    vector<MineralRocks> minerals =
    { { 3, "Li", "Lithium", 453.65, 1603.0, 0.534, 152.0, "Johan August Arfwedson", 6000.0, "Australia", 12.0 }
    , { 92, "U", "Uranium", 1405.3, 4404.0, 19.1, 156.0, "Martin Heinrich Klaproth", 3155.0, "Canada", 33.3 }
    };

// Append to vector
    minerals.emplace_back(79, "Au", "Gold", 1337.33, 3243.0, 19.30, 144.0, "Jeande Marignac", 2030.0, "China", 15.734);

// Sample display
    for (auto&& m : minerals)
        m.display();

// Test copy-construction
    MineralRocks f{minerals[0]};

}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed instructors for future implementation.  This makes perfect sense compared to my noobish ways.  Will do in the future.